# FabricJS canvas drawImage not displaying image

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, fabricjs

Attempting to create a custom class that will display an image on the top left corner of a Fabric rectangle.

Extending the fabric class and calling `ctx.drawImage` isn't displaying anything.

```js
var CustomRect = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {

  type: 'labeledRect',

  initialize: function(options) {
    options || (options = { });
    const image = new Image(); 
    image.src = signBtn; 

    this.callSuper('initialize', options);
    this.set('label', options.label || '');
    this.set('image', image);
  },

  toObject: function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
      label: this.get('label')
    });
  },

  _render: function(ctx) {
    this.callSuper('_render', ctx);

    ctx.font = '20px Helvetica';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
    ctx.fillText(this.label, -this.width/2, -this.height/2 + 20);
    ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.left+10, this.top-5, 15, 15);
  }
});
```

`fillText` is working fine and displaying the label properly.

Tried a few different things thinking the image isn't loaded. It's imported as an SVG. I've gotten it to display in other ways but prefer to have a custom class handle this instead of event handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set image after load. You can use image.onload event callback, or use [fabric.util.loadImage](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.util.html#.loadImage)

***DEMO***

```js
fabric.CustomRect = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {

  type: 'customRect',

  initialize: function(options) {
    options || (options = { });
    var that = this;
    this.imageLoaded = false;
    fabric.util.loadImage(options.signBtn,function(img){
      that.set('image', img);
      that.imageLoaded = true;
      that.dirty = true;
      //if canvas is global
      canvas.renderAll();
    },{
      crossOrigin : 'annonymous'
    });

    this.callSuper('initialize', options);
    this.set('label', options.label || '');
    
  },

  toObject: function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
      label: this.label,
      image : this.image
    });
  },

  _render: function(ctx) {
    this.callSuper('_render', ctx);

    ctx.font = '20px Helvetica';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
    ctx.fillText(this.label, -this.width/2, -this.height/2 + 20);
    this.imageLoaded && ctx.drawImage(this.image, 10, -5, 15, 15);
  }
});
  fabric.CustomRect.fromObject = function(object, callback) {
    return fabric.Object._fromObject('CustomRect', object, callback);
  };

var url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg';
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

var rect = new fabric.CustomRect({
 signBtn: url,
 left : 10,
 top : 10,
 width : 200,
 height: 200,
 fill: 'green',
 label : 'test'
});
canvas.add(rect);
function loadfromjson() {
  var json = canvas.toJSON();
  canvas.clear();
  setTimeout(function() {
    canvas.loadFromJSON(json, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
  }, 1000)
}
```

```css
canvas{
  border:2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js'></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<button onclick="loadfromjson()">loadfromjson </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are some missing values like `this.width` and `this.height`?

In addition to that, you have to wait until the image is loaded to draw it. You can do something like this:

```
var CustomRect = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {

  type: 'labeledRect',

  initialize: function(options) {
    options || (options = { });
    const image = new Image(); 
    image.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYp8Y.jpg'; 

    this.callSuper('initialize', options);

    image.onload = (function() {
        this.width = image.width;
        this.height = image.height;
        this.image_loaded = true;
      }).bind(this);


    this.set('label', options.label || '');
    this.set('image', image);
  },

  toObject: function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
      label: this.get('label')
    });
  },

  _render: function(ctx) {

    if (this.image_loaded) {
        this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
        console.log(-this.width / 2, -this.height / 2);
        ctx.font = '20px Helvetica';
        ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
        ctx.fillText(this.label, -this.width/2, -this.height/2 + 20);
        ctx.drawImage(this.image, -this.width / 2, -this.height / 2);
      }
  }
});
```

Note these two changes:

```
image.onload = (function() {
        this.width = image.width;
        this.height = image.height;
        this.image_loaded = true;
      }).bind(this);
```

I set the `image_loaded` to true inside the `initialize` method once the image is loaded. Then in the `_render` method I check if the image is loaded, and then draw it.

```
if(this.loaded){
     //............
     ctx.drawImage(this.image, -this.width / 2, -this.height / 2);
 }
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nimeshka/enL61g0w/55/

You might need to click on the canvas to trigger the `render` event. Otherwise you won't see the rectangle in the output box. (I haven't added it)
Hope it helps :)